# active_admin_editor.gemspec not vaild

Tags: rubygems, gemspecs

fresh laptop install 
trying to get work project up and running

foreman or rails start/server outputs this error =>
The gemspec at /home/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin_editor-86f964be3071/active_admin_editor.gemspec is not valid. The validation error was 'duplicate dependency on activeadmin (~> 0.4.3, development), (>= 0.4.0) use:
    add_runtime_dependency 'activeadmin', '~> 0.4.3', '>= 0.4.0'

**Edit**

I added   s.add_runtime_dependency 'activeadmin', '~> 0.4.3', '>= 0.4.0'

to the gemspec file did not fix anything, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the same problem.
It's an issue with the dependencies set in active admin editor.
Others have already reported. Have a look at [this link](https://github.com/ejholmes/active_admin_editor/issues/59).

You can turn off active admin editor until the bug is fixed.
I tried using other versions and dependencies, but it didn't help.